# Audiolib.js: Changing values of existing "objects"

Tags: javascript, audio, member-variables

so I looked into Audiolib.js and can make some basic stuff but what I don't know and can't figure out by searching through the internet.

The question is how I can change specific values of some "objects" without "re-appending" it. For example:

```js
var osc;
osc = audioLib.Oscillator(44100 /*or some other samplerate */ , 400 );

function changefrequency(freq)
osc.frequency = freq; /* is there a way to do stuff like this? */
```

(Btw. with "objects" I mean oscillators, lfo's, filters and so on.)
Since there are many other situations where I would like to change values without interrupting the whole process, I would realy like to do stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this library allows you to modify the properties of its objects. For example, [this tutorial](https://github.com/jussi-kalliokoski/audiolib.js/wiki/Tutorials%3A-Synthesizing-a-Song) is modifying the "frequency" property of the Oscillator to change notes. It also uses the "reset" method to reset its phase when changing notes.

Comment: Hi, 
the problem is what are these properties? Maybe the same as the values which are used fot the init? Like frequency and samplerate for oszillators? It looks like I have to do some trial and error...

@EDIT: I didn't noticed this when I was skimming over this tutorial, thanks. ;)